# Discord python bot creation: clear message command that shows how many messages were deleted

Tags: discord.py

I am in need of help to make bot respond to me with an exact number of how many messages were cleared.

example: When I type !clear 15 and it deletes 12 message I want it to respond me with "12 messages cleared"

I tried something like this:

```
  @commands.command()
  async def clear(self, ctx, amount=10):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.send(amount, 'messages cleared')
```

I know this wouldn't show how many messages it cleared but how many it tried to clear (of course if it did work that is what would happen but it didn't work as expected)

I searched a lot about this but I could not find any similar posts anywhere so hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

[`TextChannel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge) returns a list of messages that were deleted, you can simply use `len()`

```py
deleted_messages = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
await ctx.send(f"{len(deleted_messages) - 1} messages cleared") # Subtracting 1 as it's the message of the command
```

Also you should typehint the `amount` arg so it's automatically converted to an integer

```py
async def purge(self, ctx, amount: int = 10):
```